# Complexity order

Tags: complexity-theory

i'm needing some help to find what is the complexity order of this function:

```
int cerca_ciclos (int vet[],int nivel)
{
    int i,j,cont=0;
    if (vet[nivel-2] == vet[nivel-1]) {
            return 1; 
    }

    for (i=2;i <= nivel/2; i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
           if  (vet[nivel-j-1] == vet[nivel-1-i]){
                cont++;
                }
        }
        if (cont == i){

                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the variable Nivel will  never overflow the pré defined limit that i setted 35.

Comment: Tell us how far you got and what problem you found.

Comment: Can't define a complexity order... cause in the first loop it will make nivel/2 compares, and in the other "for" it will make i compares, but i will vary from 0 to nivel/2 (that will vary from 2 to 35)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm runs in time-complexity `O(nivel²)`

the outer `for`-loop runs from `0` to `nivel/2` and the inner runs from `0` to `i`, which is between `0` and `nivel/2`. So the count of steps to compute are

`total = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + nivel/2`

Gauß' said this is somthing like `1/2⋅(nivel/2)⋅(nivel/2+1)` so it is quadratic in `nivel`.

But due to `nivel` is boundet to 35 (or any other constant number), the complexity will be `O(1)` cause you can find a constant value that is bigger than the "worst case" number of steps, that the algorithm has to compute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with Sigma notation:

[image]